# Why is my grep command not working?

Tags: grep

I have these files:

**dd1** contains:

```
ok
stanley
```

**dd2** contains:

```
ouddd
eddi
```

**dd3** contains:

```
hello
dd1
```

---

And I used the command

`$ grep -E dd* dd1 dd2 dd3`

hoping to get all the lines that contained the letter d in them. So I was hoping to get

```
dd2: ouddd
dd2: eddi
dd3: dd1
```

but instead I got

```
dd3:dd1
dd3:dd1
```

I don't understand why I only got only the last one (dd3:dd1), and also why it gave it to me twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression that you use, `dd*`, is not quoted at all in the shell. This means that the shell will use it as a filename globbing pattern and will expand it to all matching filenames (`dd1`, `dd2`, and `dd3`).

The command, thus, will be

```
grep -E dd1 dd2 dd3 dd1 dd2 dd3
```

This runs `grep` with the pattern `dd1` across the files `dd2`, `dd3`, `dd1`, `dd2`, and `dd3`. You get two lines from from the file `dd3` because there is one line matching the expression but the file occurs twice in the list of files.

To give the pattern to `grep` unexpanded by the shell, quote it:

```
grep 'dd*' dd1 dd2 dd3
```

or, equivalently,

```
grep -E 'd+' dd[123]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote your pattern, otherwise it will expanded by the shell.

`dd*` expands to `dd1 dd2 dd3`

So you actually run:

```
grep -E dd1 dd2 dd3 dd1 dd2 dd3
```

You want

```
grep -E 'dd*' dd1 dd2 dd3
```

But to get every lines with a `d`, you can just run:

```
grep -F 'd' dd1 dd2 dd3
```